# Laravel: Send Notifications in a Batch

Tags: php, laravel, queue

## Explanation

I have a Notification that can have optional attachments.  I would like the process to be:

1. user modifies text of notification and optionally attaches file
2. if file is uploaded, move it to temporary location on server and create an Attachment model
3. send all notifications as a batch job with attachments if necessary
4. listen for `NotificationSent::class` event and check if all notifications have been sent (using `$event->notification->batching()`)
5. if the batch is finished sending, delete all attachments uploaded for that notification from server

### More Details

I have a Notification class called `CustomEmail`

```php
class CustomEmail extends Notification implements ShouldQueue 
{
    use Queueable, Batchable;
    /* regular notification methods */
}
```

In `EventServiceProvider.php` I'm listening for the `NotificationSent::class` and I made a custom `DeleteEmailAttachments` handler:

```
/** EventServiceProvider.php */

protected $listen = [
    NotificationSent::class => [
        DeleteEmailAttachments::class,
    ],
];
```

```php
/** DeleteEmailAttachments.php */

public function handle(NotificationSent $event): void
{
    Log::debug('finished sending yet? '.($event->notification->batching() ? 'yes' : 'no'));
}
```

And finally, this is how I've attempted to dispatch the job:

```php
/** EmailController.php */

// create attachment models (simplified a lot of stuff here but this is the general idea)
$attachments = [];
foreach (request()->file('attachments') as $attachment) {
    $attachments[] = App\Models\Attachment::create([
        // attachment data here
    ]);
    Storage::disk('local')->put('tempAttachments/'.$attachment->getClientOriginalName(), $attachment, 'private');
}

// create Collection of users to email
$recipients = User::whereIn('id', $request->userIds)->get();

// dispatch Notification in a batch
Bus::batch([
    Notification::send($recipients, new CustomEmail($request->body, $request->subject, $attachments)),
])->dispatch();
```

## Problem

If I add the `->dispatch()` method (as shown above), it gives me an error

```
Call to a member function withBatchId() on null
```

If I remove `->dispatch()`, the emails get sent, but the batch never gets created (no new rows in the `job_batches` table). And `$event->notification->batching()` always returns false.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to first create a job that sends the notification and dispatch the job.

Suppose you created a job `SendEmailJob`, then you can do the following:

```
Bus::batch([
    new SendEmailJob($parameters)
])->dispatch();
```